# Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.4.0'] was not found in any of the following sources

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

Generated default project start.spring.io Gradle, Java 11, Spring boot 2.4.0

[image]

```
$ cat build.gradle 
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

```
$ gradle --version
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx1024m -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=XXX -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/Users/kolisko/Documents/kb/jssecacerts

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.7.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-11-16 17:09:24 UTC
Revision:     2972ff02f3210d2ceed2f1ea880f026acfbab5c0

Kotlin:       1.3.72
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.8 compiled on May 10 2020
JVM:          15.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 15.0.1+9)
OS:           Mac OS X 11.0.1 x86_64
```

```
$ gradle build
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx1024m -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=XXX -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/Users/kolisko/Documents/kb/jssecacerts

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/kolisko/IdeaProjects/codenow/mko-java-spring-gradle/build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.4.0'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:2.4.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 485ms
```

Answer (score 0):

restarting macOS solved the problem